# What is $\#Hom(D_{24}, D_{18})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am willing to find the number of group homomorphisms from $D_{24}$ to $D_{18}$ where $D_n=\{r_n, f_n: r_n^n=f_n^2=(r_nf_n)^2=e_n\}$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$.

We know that if $\phi:D_{24}\rightarrow D_{18}$ be one such group homomoprhism then we just have to focus on the possible choice of $\phi(r_{24})$ and $\phi(f_{24})$ in $D_{18}$.

What next ? Can some one help me out please ?

Comment: Is there something special about $D_{18}$ and $D_{24}$?(or Is this a homework problem).

Comment: Ohh no no. not at all homework problem,. I am trying to understand step by step. If m, n are odd/odd or even/odd then I know how to solve the problem. Next challenge is odd/even and even/even. I think if we be able to solve even/even then odd/even will be handled easily. This is why I chose the case even/even. Although don't know how to finish :-(

Comment: But even then why did you choose 18 and 24? You can have a look at this paper:http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.2363.pdf

Comment: That paper is my motivation. I have already gone through the paper but the even/even case I found confusing. So I rather considered numerical example so that understanding the particular example will help me to understand the proof. Would you mind to make it clear to me ?

Comment: Sorry,right now I'm little bit busy.I'll write back to you asap.Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you need to focus on the possible images of $R:=\phi(r_{24})$ and $F:=\phi(f_{24})$, more precisely the images chosen should verify in $D_{18}$ the relations they verify in $D_{24}$ that is you should have :

$$R^{24}=F^2=(RF)^2=Id $$

Now you have $18$+$1$+$1$ choices of elements of order $2$ for $F$. Namely $r_{18}^kf_{18}$ ($0\leq k\leq 17$), $r_{18}^9$ and $1$. If $F=1$ then you only need to have $R^2=1$ so you have likewise $20$ choices.

If $F=r_{18}^9$ then $F$ is central so $R$ only need to be of order $2$ so you have also $20$ choices.

If $F=r_{18}^kf_{18}$, assume that $R=r_{18}^lf_{18}$ then $R^2=Id$ and $RF=r_{18}^{k-l}$ so that $RF^2=1$ if and only if $l=9-k$ or $l=-k$ (mod $18$) so you  have, for any $k$, $2$ choices : hence $36$ choices.

Else $F=r_{18}^kf_{18}$ and $R=r_{18}^l$ in which case $F^2=(RF)^2=1$. Hence you only need to check $R^{24}=1$. This happens if and only if $o(R)$ divides $24$, since it should also divides $18$ it will divide $6$. Since you have $1$, $r_{18}^3$, $r_{18}^{6}$, $r_{18}^{9}$,$r_{18}^{12}$, $r_{18}^{15}$. You finally get $6$ elements.

Finally, for any $k$ you get $6$ choices hence $108$ choices. On the whole, I would say $188$ different morphisms.

Comment: Just now I opened this website and saw your message/answer. Today I have figured out the matter and I am happy thats correct because of your reply. Thank you so much for your help. It is cleared to me now

Comment: between I need to understand one thing, would you mind me telling if right or not ? Is it true that there is a bijection from the set $Hom(G_1\oplus G_2, H_1\oplus H_2)$ to set $Hom(G_1, H_1)\times Hom(G_1, H_2)\times Hom(G_2, H_1)\times (G_2, H_2)$ for any arbitrary groups $G_1, G_2, H_1, H_2$ ?

Comment: Yes it is true, to formalize it I would use projection and restriction morphisms.

Comment: Are you sure there is no abelian group cases are involved ? Cause I have confusion if it is true for Abelian groups only.

Comment: @Anjan, I don't really know about the non-abelian case (although I am pretty sure that this does not work). This holds for abelian case (you used $\oplus$, it means to me that you are in an abelian category).

Comment: Opps !! my mistake. I am sorry. editing. I meant to ask for direct prduct only . Thank you for your advice although :-)

Comment: Dear Sir. I tried to solve #Hom$(D_{20}, D_{40})$ myself in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439529/please-find-the-mistake-if-any-in-calculating-homd-20-d-40?noredirect=1#comment2932438_1439529 would you please check it ?