# Please find the mistake (if any) in calculating $\#Hom(D_{20}, D_{40})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can some one tell me how shall I finish ?

We have to find the number of group homomorphisms from $D_{20}$ to $D_{40}$. Please note that I have asked the similar question [which can be found here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423809/what-is-homd-24-d-18/1424987#1424987)
But the thing is, instead of copy paste of the previous answer this times I have taken effort to do it myself. So I am going to write here each and every step. Please tell me if I made any mistake.

Alright, so let $\rho:D_{20}\rightarrow D_{40}$ be a group homomorphism. And since $D_{20}$ is generated by $r_{20}, f_{20}$ because 
$$D_n:=\langle r_n, f_n:r_n^n=f_n^2=(r_nf_n)^2=e_n  \rangle$$
so we just have concentrate on the $\rho$ images of $r_{20}, f_{20}$ such that they will satisfy 
$$[\rho(r_{20})\rho(f_{20})]^2=e_{40}.....................(1)$$

Now $|\rho(r_{20})|$ divides $|r_{20}|, |D_{40}|$ and hence divides $(20, 80)=20$ and similarly $\rho(f_{20})$ divides $|f_{20}|, |D_{40}|$ and hence divides $(|f_{20}|, |D_{40}|)=2$. Which shows that

$$\rho(r_{20})=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
   e_{40} , & \hbox{1-ordered;} \\
   r_{40}^{20}, & \hbox{2-ordered.}\\
   r_{40}^\beta f_{40}, & 0 \leq \beta \leq 39~~\hbox{2-ordered}\\
   r_{40}^i, & |r_{40}^i|>2, |r_{40}^i|\Big |20.
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

$$\rho(f_{20})=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
   e_{40} , & \hbox{1-ordered;} \\
   r_{40}^{20}, & \hbox{2-ordered.}\\
   r_{40}^\beta f_{40}, & 0 \leq \beta \leq 39~~\hbox{2-ordered}
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

**Case: $\rho(r_{20})=e_{40}.$**
Then we can take $\rho(f_{40})\in \{e_{40}, r_{40}^{20}, f_{40}, r_{40}f_{40}, \cdots, r_{40}^{39}f_{40}\}$ to satisfy $(1)$ and hence we get $1+1+40$ correct choices.

**Case: $|\rho(r_{20})|>2.$**
This means $\rho(r_{20})$ must be of the form $r_{40}^i\in \langle r_{40} \rangle$. For each order $d$ there will be $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$. In other words for $\rho(r_{40})$ will have $\varphi(4)+\varphi(5)+\varphi(10)+\varphi(20)=\sum\limits_{d|20, d\neq 1,2}\varphi(d)$ choices. For each choice, i.e. if $\rho(r_{20})=r_{40}^i, |r_{20}^i|>2$ we can take $\rho(f_{20})\in \{r_{40}^\beta f_{40}:0\leq \beta\leq 39 \}$ in order to satisfy $(1)$ and then we get $40$ choices for $\rho(f_{20})$. And combining we get $\left(\sum\limits_{d|20, d\neq 1, 2}\varphi(d)\right)\times 40$ new entries.

**Case: $|\rho(r_{20})|=2.$**
In this case, we shall get either $\rho(r_{20})=r_{40}^{20}$ or $\rho(r_{20})=r_{40}^\beta f_{40}: 0\leq \beta \leq 39$.

If $\rho(r_{20})=r_{40}^{20}$, then to satisfy $(1)$ we need to take $\rho(f_{20})\in \{e_{40}, r_{40}^{20}, r_{40}^\beta f_{40}: \beta=0, 1, \cdots, 39\}$ and we get $1+1+40$ new choices.

If $\rho(r_{20})=r_{40}^\beta f_{40}: 0\leq \beta\leq 39$ then?
First we can take $\rho(f_{20})=e_{40}$ to get $40$ new choices.

Then we can take $\rho(f_{20})=r_{40}^\alpha f_{20}: 0\leq \alpha\leq 39$ which will by $(1)$ eventually show that $\beta-\alpha=\pm 20$. Since there 40 such ordered pair $(\beta, \alpha)$, we get 40 more new entries.

Finally we can take $\rho(f_{20})=r_{40}^{20}$ to satisfy $(1)$ and here we shall get 40 new choices.

I don't bother about the final result but just interested in my argument. So respected every one, would you please take your time and let me know if I had made any mistake above?

Thanks in advance

**Final Count:**
$(1+1+40)+\left(\sum\limits_{d|20, d\neq 1, 2}\varphi(d)   \right)\times 40+(1+1+40)+(40+40+40)$

Comment: Do you have any motivation for all these calculations?

Comment: I first came to know from this research paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.2363.pdf but then it was difficult for me to understand the even/even case. So I started the work myself

Comment: The correct ans is 964 whereas mine is 924. 40 still missing. No idea where did I miss. Please help someone!! :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case: $|\rho(r_{20})|=2.$**

Your claim :

$\rho(r_{20})=r_{40}^\beta f_{40}$ then we have one choice of $\rho(f_{20})$ of the form $r_{40}^{\alpha}f_{40}$, it is given by $\alpha:=\beta+ 20[40]$.

My claim : You could also choose $\alpha:=\beta[40]$. Hence in this particular case you get $2$ ordered pairs for each $\beta$ :

$$(\beta,\beta)\text{ and } (\beta,\beta+20) $$

So that you have $2\times 40$ choices instead of $40$.